# Cleaning string by removing symbols

Tags: python, regex

I have to clean a string removing special symbols `/#$%^&*@0123456789`only if they are separated from each other by letters or symbols not in the list.
Example:

```
H8e%&l6&%l@8095o a@/9^65$n228d w%e60$$#&9l3@/c6o5m3e --> Hello and welcome
I1^/0^^@9t #$%% i/@4#s 11P17/9$M 5^&* a^$45$5$0n&##^4d 6^&&* I $%^$%^ a8@@94%3*m t3120i36&^1r2&^##0e&^d ---> It #$%% is 11PM 5^&* and 6^&&* I $%^$%^ am tired
,. a3%2%1/3$s*0. d8^! -->,. as. d!
##%12Symbols on the left must remain untouched --> ##%12Symbols on the left must remain untouched
```

I figured out that it's possible to do using `re.sub`:

```
import re
def _correct_message(message):
    new_final_string = re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z\.\!])[/#\$\%\^\&\*\@0123456789]+(?=[a-zA-Z\.\!])", '', message)
    return new_final_string
```

But I don't like the fact that I have to add symbols which is not in the list `.!.?` manually. Is it possible to make it without `regex`?

Comment: You could iterate over the string, check each character and if the following one is a special one too and then remove it if not.

Comment: Just to assist you with regex: have a look at following website: https://regex101.com It translates regex expressions

Answer (score 0):

It is the closest I could get:

```
 (\W+|\d{1,}(?!\d\[A-Za-z]))(?![A-Za-z]{2,})
```

Just replace all matches with space